# Aligning img in center of a display:inline-block element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am using a global class I have `.total-center` to try and align the image in the center of `bonus-left`. For some reason the img is going outside of the container `bonus-left`...

[image]

Does anyone see why my image is not centering vertically within the `bonus-left` div?

```css
.total-center {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#review-bonus {
  width: 99%;
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#review-bonus-inner {
  padding: 20px;
}

#bonus-left,
#bonus-right {
  display: inline-block;
}
#bonus-right {
  width: 75%;
 } 

#bonus-left {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

#bonus-left img {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="review-bonus">
  <div id="review-bonus-inner">
    <div id="bonus-left">
      <div class="total-center"><img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i60915/himacchi/sweetbox/gift.ico"></div>
    </div><div id="bonus-right">
      <h3 id="bonus-title">FREE</h3>
      <p id="bonus-description">f jdkl fnjfn rweofnrfnfndafndffn ddfd fdhfanjk herowf fhrgfndfndf wfefnanf fefnf f hqaf hef fewh f hfewanf f aWFH F HWEEFNDNADS ANDJFDNF E </p>
      <ul>
        <li>g erj iroehgnvfd f nvjvhrnvjf nevj nvonvrfvnfvn envdvn nfereonovfnjofnvf oegnpvnfdonvfognoa</li>
        <li>fndj iofgh rionrn ;nn oej rejbnvofn noe revofnoa;gvan</li>
        <li>h trhth thwgh 4t ththhthtw th aregtrhw</li>
        <li>htr htrh twh htrh thth twhtr hwht w</li>
        <li>grtg regh htrw hthtthwhth tr th twhw hhttwhtrh w h</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you need to know about CSS and HTML to understand my tweaks:

- Browsers will actually render the whitespace between elements. This is why if your container is width:100% and your children are width:25% and width:75%, it wraps onto the next line. If you remove the whitespace in the HTML between the parent and children, it fits perfectly.
- If you CANNOT remove this whitespace, you may need to resort to using float and the "clearfix" hack. But since I can control the whitespace, I will implement that way only.
- You don't need a wrapper around the image just to totally center the contents. This can usually be done with just CSS. In my tweak, I told the img to be width:100% and didn't bother with the height or the position. The alignment is left to the parents.
- Vertical alignment is tricky. In this case, you need to think of it as applying to all siblings of a parent. I told bonus-left and bonus-right to both align vertically in the middle, which means that the taller one will provide guidance for the shorter one. Just giving vertical-align:middle to the bonus-left will default to vertical-align:top for bonus-right, which means the bonus-left middle will align vertically with the bonus-right top. Tricky tricky.

```css
#review-bonus {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#review-bonus-inner {
  padding: 20px;
}

#bonus-left,
#bonus-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#bonus-right {
  width: 75%;
 } 

#bonus-left {
  width: 25%;
}

#bonus-left img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="review-bonus">
  <div id="review-bonus-inner"><div id="bonus-left">
      <img src="http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i60915/himacchi/sweetbox/gift.ico">
    </div><div id="bonus-right">
      <h3 id="bonus-title">FREE</h3>
      <p id="bonus-description">f jdkl fnjfn rweofnrfnfndafndffn ddfd fdhfanjk herowf fhrgfndfndf wfefnanf fefnf f hqaf hef fewh f hfewanf f aWFH F HWEEFNDNADS ANDJFDNF E </p>
      <ul>
        <li>g erj iroehgnvfd f nvjvhrnvjf nevj nvonvrfvnfvn envdvn nfereonovfnjofnvf oegnpvnfdonvfognoa</li>
        <li>fndj iofgh rionrn ;nn oej rejbnvofn noe revofnoa;gvan</li>
        <li>h trhth thwgh 4t ththhthtw th aregtrhw</li>
        <li>htr htrh twh htrh thth twhtr hwht w</li>
        <li>grtg regh htrw hthtthwhth tr th twhw hhttwhtrh w h</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding vertical align on bonus-left and bonus-right will fix this

```
#bonus-left,
#bonus-right {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You might want to add max-width on your image as well. On wide screen it will be too big and overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Add vertical align: top to #bonus-right will solve your problem

```
 #bonus-left {
        width: 25%;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Try this